# Ignoring folders for ever in Git

Tags: git

when I do a git status that is what I get

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .idea/
```

this **.idea/ folder** is something coming from IntelliJ and RubyMine but I don't want it to be added to my Git.  And when I say `git add .`  I still want to be able to do that but not include .ida/ folder.

What is the correct git command to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
.idea
```

and any other paths you want to ignore in a file called `.gitignore` inside your repo (and track this using Git). See [`gitignore(5)`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

To `.gitconfig` or `.git/info/exclude` add the following:

```
.idea/
```

The former can be commited and becomes part of the repository. The latter is better suited for per-user settings that should not affect other users.